# Stopping MS Windows 10 from uninstalling Java's JDK

Tags: windows-10, java, windows-update, jdk

My laptop runs `MS Windows 10 Home` OS. I've got `JDK (Java Development Kit)` at version 7, that I use for software development. The current available version of Java SE (Standard Edition) is version 8, although I keep on my laptop version 7.

Now the OS receives updates constantly. What it does, is that after each update it uninstalls the JDK at version 7 and replaces it with JDK version 8. The `JRE (Java Runtime Environment)` yet stays at version 7.

I need the JDK for software development, when the JRE I can use only to run Java software. Specifically, I need the JDK at version 7.

Is there a way on the OS to control what changes get applied after each update? Now, what I do, is that I need to reinstall the JDK v7 after each update, which are frequent. Or, is there any way to keep older version of JDK, v7, untouched?

Comment: Windows doesn't install the JDK. You need to look at your JDK settings and 1/ stop auto update. 2/ Configure it not to remove old version.

Comment: Hm, I get the latest version of JDK after each and every Windows update, nowadays. Before it was not so. Maybe that a new Windows's 10 feature? In the past, I believe, it was possible to enable/disable Java update on Java icon at Windows's Programs icon.  Now, that feature is gone, as what I can see now.

Comment: Windows Update, if it actually is installing JRE 8, isn't replacing JRE 7 with JRE 8 it is just installing 8.  It might be changing your system variables but that is easy enough to solve.  I am with David, Windows Update, has never to my knowlege installed JDE, and it is not a Windows Feature, that only exists on Windows 10.